# Trying to Pass Multiple Variables from Multiple Windows through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to pass multiple variables from two different windows into the same PHP script. Is this possible? If not, what would be the best course of action?

Thanks

verifyemail.html

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/js_functions.js"> </script>  
<form method="post" onsubmit = "return testAjax();" />
    <input   type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" required maxlength = "50"><br>
    <input  type="email" placeholder="re-enter email"name="reemail" required maxlength = "50"><br>              
    <input type="submit" value="Verify Email"> 
</form>

<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

signup.html:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="js/js_functions.js"></script>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return ajaxTest();"/>
            <input   type="text" placeholder="username" name="username"     required = "required" maxlength = "15"><br>
            <input  type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" required = "required" pattern = "(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{10,}"><br>
            <input  type="password" placeholder="re-enter password"name="repassword" required = "required"><br>
            <p class = "passwordreq">Password must:</p>

            <input type="submit" value="sign up"> <input type="button" value="go back"  onclick="window.location='index.html'">
        </form>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

js_functions

```
var username, password;
function setUsrandPass(form)
{
if(form.password.value != form.repassword.value)
{
    alert("Passwords do not match");

}

else {
    username = form.username.value;
    password = form.password.value; 

    window.location = 'verifyemail.html';

}

return false; 
}

function ajaxTest()
{
if(form.email.value != form.reemail.value)
{
    alert("Emails do not match");

}

else
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'signup_script.php',
    data: {usr: username, pass: password, em: form.email.value},
});

return false; 
}
```

php script:

```
<?php 

include 'profile_Functions.php';

$username = $_GET['usr'];
$password = $_GET['pass'];
$email = $_GET['em'];

echo "got here!";

createUser($username,$password,$email);
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to submit forms from two pages at the same time? i.e open in different tabs?

Comment: I want the inputs from both the signup and the verifyemail to be run in the php script at the same time

Comment: are they both displayed on a single page?

Comment: No, they are on separate pages

Comment: So are you trying to submit both forms at once? If not then they don't need to run in the php script at the same time and if you are then I don't know why, it's not something that is normally done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with things from separate pages. They need to be making the same request to the PHP script to provide both data.

You may be able to circumvent this by writing with PHP to some sort of datastore, i.e. a file or a database, then you wait for the other script to write as well, and then PHP can do any processing it needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help!